# On Mac With Apple M1 Chip, Kong Install Generates Zero Byte Key Files

Tags: kong

I am on a Mac with Apple M1 chip. After doing `brew install kong` and `kong migrations bootstrap` and trying `kong start` (failed to start), I see the following zero-byte key files created (reason for the failed start) ...

```
~ ls -l /opt/homebrew/opt/kong/ssl
total 0
-r-xr-----  1 nv  admin  0 Jan 15 03:39 admin-kong-default-ecdsa.key
-r-x------  1 nv  admin  0 Jan 14 21:16 admin-kong-default.key
-r-x------  1 nv  admin  0 Jan 14 21:04 kong-default-ecdsa.key
-r-x------  1 nv  admin  0 Jan 14 20:24 kong-default.key
```

Any idea how to recreate them with non-zero bytes?